# Metallic Engine Sound Coming from 2005 Nissan Altima

Tags: engine, noise, nissan, altima

My car recently started making a sound coming from the engine. It's hard to describe, but it's something like a mix of metallic and squeaking. I thought it would be better if I recorded it:

[Listen to sound](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLl9esAaYtY)

What could this sound be? I'm concerned, as I rely heavily on this car. I plan on taking the car to a mechanic this weekend but would like some opinions so I can know what to expect.

What part is the most likely culprit? What can I expect to pay as far as parts and labor? Different opinions are welcomed.

Comment: I would inspect the accessory drive belt and anything it turns.

Answer (score 0):

Full time professional mechanic here. that sound is very not good. Have you checked the oil? I'm guessing there is none, because that sound is metal engine/transmission parts rubbing together. if thats the case then consider the engine scrap metal.

Comment: Hi Matt, I checked the oil. It's full and clean as a whistle. This baby drives very well too. Very low miles for a 2005, just 92,000. Great condition besides this sound that started just a couple of days ago. What else could it be?

Comment: Always check the simple stuff first!  I'd look at the serpentine drive belt tensioner, the  alternator, the water pump, the power steering pump first.  Those are all attached to the engine and generally make noise as you have when they are failing.  I'm not saying it couldn't be something more serious like a major engine fault but that seems much less likely to me at this point.